# validatesLengthOf not working on password field due to hashing

Tags: loopbackjs

I am trying to validate the password when a user is registered, but the validation is not done on the plain text but hashed value. How do i fix this?

My user model is `client`:

```
module.exports = function(client) {
  client.validatesLengthOf('password', {min: 20})
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validations are for a model itself. I mean it affects on operation hooks not remote hooks.

You need to create a remote hook like this :

```
client.beforeRemote('create', function(ctx, instance, next){
  if(ctx.args.data.password.length < 20){
    return next(PsswordValidationError);  
    /* assuming you have this error object 
       or return any error validation you want */
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: I was hoping this was a builtin feature.. Too bad! Does PasswordValidation Error exist?

Comment: @JavaCake No. `PasswordValidation` doesn't exist.